# JSON expected Int but found String Swift

Tags: json, swift

i try to get some results from a json file. Everything works fine except with int. If I request team name then there is no problem.
With this Code I request the away score. But I get this error.

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Int, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "scores", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "home_score", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Int but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

It looks like I have to change the away_score: Int to away_score: String right? Because it says found a string. But that also doesnt work. It says intValue nil. How can that be nil? The result is 2. Do I have to use optionals? In other tutorials there was no need for optional for simple request like this.

```
 func parseJSON(weatherFile: Data) {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do{
           let decodedFile =  try decoder.decode(WeatherFile.self, from: weatherFile)
         print(decodedFile.data[0].scores.away_score)
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

This is my struct File:

```
struct WeatherFile: Decodable{
    let data: [Mannschaft]
}

struct Mannschaft: Decodable {
    let status_name: String
    let teams: Teams
    let scores: Scores
}
 
struct Teams:Decodable {
    let home: Away
    let away: Away
}

struct Scores: Decodable {
    let home_score: Int
    let away_score: Int
}
struct Away: Decodable {
    let name: String
}
```

This is my json

```
{
*       "data": [
    * {
        *       "id": "33153",
        *       "time": {6 items},
        *       "league": {6 items},
        *       "scores": {
            *       "home_score": "0",
            *       "away_score": "2",
            *       "ht_score": "0-1",
            *       "ft_score": "0-2",
            *       "et_score": null,
            *       "ps_score": null
        *       },
```

Comment: The error message says it all, the home_score is a string in your json but you have declared it to be an int in your struct. Change the declaration in Scores or write a custom `init(from:)` to convert it.

Comment: Thank you. But as I said above when I changed it to String it still says the result is null. I get then this error: valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 22", intValue: 22), CodingKeys(stringValue: "scores", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "home_score", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear, you've to declare `home_score` and `away_score` as type `String`. Use `computed-property` if you want to use home_score as an `Int`.

```
struct Scores: Decodable {
    let home_score, away_score: String?

    var homeScore: Int? { Int(home_score ?? "") } // or use nil coalescing.
    var awayScore: Int? { Int(away_score ?? "") }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but still same problem. It finds a null instead of a string. This was the error: valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 22", intValue: 22), CodingKeys(stringValue: "scores", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "home_score", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Seems you've to use optional string: `String?`. Check the update.

Comment: Yes it worked now. I also used ! on the other side to unwrap.It is very strange why it was like that. In other tutorials i never had problem with those things.